# Date with 2 year digit string to timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I have this date string for example:

> 10/01/14 14:00

which would be

> d/m/y H:i

How can i convert it to timestamp? Considering that (/) slashes are not valid and 2 digit year is not accepted by strtodate.

Comment: Use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to create a DateTime object. Then use `$datetime->getTimestamp()` to convert it into a timestamp.

Comment: I beleave that the table with proper formats on this link should help you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: No problem, @Jack. It can be done with a one-liner: `echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y H:i', '10/01/14 14:00')->getTimestamp();`